# EditText cut in half by Soft Keyboard in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to create a chat layout so I've got a recyclerview with an EditText (which use a rounded corner background) and a ImageButton to send the message, however when the soft keyboard shows up, it covers a little part of the EditText and the ImageButton.

I have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in my `AndroiManifest`

I've tried:

- using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize` it was taking everything up, my `BottomNavigationView` included (which I don't want)
- putting `app:paddingBottomSystemWindowInsets="@{true}"` on my ConstraintLayout

Here is my layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_support"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/et_support"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:reverseLayout="true"
            tools:itemCount="3"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_support_received" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_support"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn_support_send"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rv_support"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_support_send"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/et_support"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rv_support" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

and below my 2 images showing the issue:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround by doing this:

1. I've gone back to `adjustPan` in my AndroidManifest
2. In my fragment I've added:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
activity?.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    // Extension method I've created to hide/show the bottomNav
    requireActivity().showBottomNavBar(false)
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    requireActivity().showBottomNavBar(true)
activity?.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a bottom padding of "16" to your recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have implement as below, in this

1. added scrollview in layout file
2. change in app themes

   ```
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
   ```

and layout file as

```
     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.FirstActivity">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"

        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/layout_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_container">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_get_started"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten_dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_box"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/button_color"
                    android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp"
                    android:text="Get Started" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sample_tour"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten_dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_border"
                    android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp"
                    android:text="Sample Tour"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_color" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ten_dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_box"
                android:hint="Enter booking code"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                android:padding="@dimen/five_dp"
                android:textColorHint="#A1887F"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And thats all, Happy Coding :)